# How do I enable directory listing in a specific IIS folder via web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config

I have this as my `web.config` in my `images` folder:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But no dice.

Any help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On IIS 7 and above you could use the following.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <configuration>
                <system.webServer>
                    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
                </system.webServer>
        </configuration>
```

On IIS 6 you'll have to configure it via IIS Manager.

Comment: Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Configuration file web.config does not have root <configuration> tag

Source Error:

Line 1:  <system.webServer>
Line 2:          <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
Line 3:      </system.webServer>